# Adjusting Column Widths in Tables

Tags: tables, multicolumn, arrays, columns, textwidth

I'm new to Latex and struggling with adjusting the widths of a few columns in a Table. From the table attached here, I just need columns 2 & 4 to be reduced so that column 5 can be enlarged.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
\begin{table*}


\begin{adjustbox}{max width=1.0\textwidth}


\begin{threeparttable}


%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%


caption{Variables used and their practical applications. Program placement and best uses of each described throughout the text.}


\begin{tabular}{M M M M M}\toprule

\multicolumn{1}{M}{Metric} & \multicolumn{1}{M}{Test} &


\multicolumn{1}{M}{Definition} &

\multicolumn{1}{M}{Unit} & \multicolumn{1}{M}{Practical Application} \\

\midrule
```

Any help or tips to show I'm going wrong is appreciated. I've tried using M{} with a set width or relative but still nothing....

Thank you[image]

Comment: use `l` not `M` for columns 2,4 so they are set their natural width

Comment: Where is your header ;)

Comment: note you can mark code blocks on this site using the `{}` button or with three backticks as I just did. It really helps if you always provide a complete test document not a fragment, so that people can test answers (and know how big your page is, for example). It is commented out which is good but never apply `\resizebox` to tables, it makes inconsistent font and rule sizes. But same applies to `\begin{adjustbox}{max width=1.0\textwidth}`

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XlXlXl}` or something similar might help.

Comment: To save some horizontal space and in order to reduce the overall amount of unused white space in the table, you could also just use teh abbreviated form in the first column. You could add a list of the long and the abbreviated in a tablenote below the actual table.

Comment: I think caption should be \caption ... anyway, as I said, you should post your complete header (the part of code before \begin{document}). This would allow users to answer to you properly